# Calling .NET assembly from Delphi/C++Builder

Tags: .net, delphi, interface, c++builder

I tried to use the `TBluetoothLE` component in a multi-platform application. The code works fine on iOS. Needs some tweaking to work correctly on Android. But I am not able to make it work on Windows.

I looked during debugging at the source code on the Windows platform, and it seems to use the WinRT API. I know that writing (and testing) a generic component that works well on several platforms is not so easy.  But I'm wondering if we can use the WinRT directly from the application without using the component provided by Embarcadero.

There are many working examples in C# that I tested on Windows. [BluetoothLEExplorer](https://github.com/Microsoft/BluetoothLEExplorer) is a very good application that show the use of WinRT to discover and communicate with BLE devices.

Delphi also provides interface files to use WinRT, but there is no sample application showing how to use it.

I would like to investigate a very simple example of calling a function inside a .NET assembly from C++Builder.

In C#, a simple example is to call `FromBluetoothAddressAsync` to find if a BLE device with a given address is connectable:

C# example in 3 lines of code:

1- create a Watcher to discover BLE devices

```cs
BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher advWatcher;
// then call its Received method 
advWatcher.Received(some_callback_function_to_be_called_when_the_watcher_detect_adevice);
//the discovered BLE device address is saved in variable uint_t64 deviceAddr by the callback_function
```

2- get a `BluetoothLEDevice` object for the device using `FromBluetoothAddressAsync()`:

```cs
BluetoothLEDevice dev = BluetoothLEDevice::FromBluetoothAddressAsync(deviceAddr).get();
```

In the .NET assembly `Windows.Device.Bluetooth`, the signature of the `FromBluetoothAddressAsync()` function is:

```cs
inline Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::BluetoothLEDevice> BluetoothLEDevice::FromBluetoothAddressAsync(uint64_t bluetoothAddress)
```

Delphi provides interfaces to the `BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher` and `BluetoothLEDevice` classes, and the `Received()` and `FromBluetoothAddressAsync()` methods, inside `WinAPI.Devices.Bluetooth.pas`.

From the C++Builder side, we have the header files for the definitions. In `Winapi.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement.hpp` we have:

```cpp
__interface DELPHIINTERFACE IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher;
typedef System::DelphiInterface<IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher> _di_IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher;
```

and in `WinAPI.Devices.Bluetooth.hpp` we have:

```cpp
  class PASCALIMPLEMENTATION TBluetoothDevice : public System::Win::Winrt::TWinRTGenericImportS2__2<_di_IBluetoothDeviceStatics,_di_IBluetoothDeviceStatics2>
{
    typedef System::Win::Winrt::TWinRTGenericImportS2__2<_di_IBluetoothDeviceStatics,_di_IBluetoothDeviceStatics2> inherited;

public:
    ...
    static _di_IAsyncOperation_1__IBluetoothDevice __fastcall FromBluetoothAddressAsync(unsigned __int64 address);

public:
    /* TObject.Create */ inline __fastcall TBluetoothDevice() : System::Win::Winrt::TWinRTGenericImportS2__2<_di_IBluetoothDeviceStatics,_di_IBluetoothDeviceStatics2>() { }
    /* TObject.Destroy */ inline __fastcall virtual ~TBluetoothDevice() { }

};
```

My question is : how to make instances of .NET objects in C++Builder?

I understand that a statement like:

```cpp
_di_IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher MyWatacher;
```

in C++Builder is just a declaration. This means that `MyWatcher` is a NULL pointer. But how to create an instance of a new (real) `BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher` object before calling its methods?

**Update #1**

My understanding is that for each invokable class `_X` in .NET assembly, delphi will generate two definitions: the interface `I_X` and the object `T_X`. We can "Create/Allocate" instances of `T_X` but not of `I_X`. In C++Builder we get another name for the interface `_di_I_X`.

Creating the object seems ok :

```cpp
    TBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher *inst =
    new TBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher();
    _di_IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher intf;
```

I tried several approaches to typecast the created `T_X` to `_di_I_X` :

//First method :

```cpp
inst->GetInterface(__uuidof(IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher), (void*)&intf);
```

//Second method :

```cpp
intf = interface_cast<TBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher>(inst);
```

//Third method :

```
bool trans_ok = Supports(inst,__uuidof(IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher),(void*)&intf);
```

All of them return a NULL for  `intf`.

I noticed that `TBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher` is declared by :

```cpp
TBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher= class(TWinRTGenericImportFI<IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherFactory, IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher>)
```

Do you think that "the type casting issue" is related to multiple inheritance in `TBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher` ?

**Update #2:**

I used delphi to create an instance for me.
I created a `unit2.pas` with :

```
unit Unit2;

interface
uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Bluetooth,  Winapi.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement;

function CreateADelphiInstance() : IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher;
implementation

  function CreateADelphiInstance() : IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher;
begin
  Result := TBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher.Create;
end;
end.
```

Then in C++ Builder I call it by:

```
_di_IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher intf = CreateADelphiInstance();
if (intf) 
    intf->ScanningMode = Winapi::Commontypes::BluetoothLEScanningMode::Active;
```

But I hope being able to do this directly in C++Builder.

Comment: Thank you for editing Remy. I was really waiting your help.

Comment: The `T_X` classes *implement* the `I_X` interfaces, so you can assign a `T_X*` pointer to an `I_X*` pointer. That is normal polymorphism at work. The `_di_I_X` types are just typedefs of the `DelphiInterface` helper class, which wraps `I_X*` pointers to handle reference counting like  Delphi does natively. You should be able to use `_di_IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher intf = new TBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher();` which is the equivalent of the Delphi code you have.

Comment: The compiler do not like to do that : `[bcc64 Error] no viable conversion from 'Winapi::Devices::Bluetooth::Advertisement::TBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher *' to '_di_IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher' (aka 'DelphiInterface<Winapi::Devices::Bluetooth::Advertisement::IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher>')`

Comment: the `DelphiInterface` class has a constructor that takes an `I_X*` pointer as input, so try using an explicit typecast from `T_X*` to `I_X*`: `_di_IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher intf = static_cast<IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher*>(new TBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher);`

Comment: The C++ compiler is considering them two different types : `[bcc64 Error] static_cast from 'Winapi::Devices::Bluetooth::Advertisement::TBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher *' to 'Winapi::Devices::Bluetooth::Advertisement::IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher *' is not allowed`.

Comment: What does the actual C++ declaration of the `TBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher` class look like?  I don't have a Bluetooth-enabled version of the IDE to look at. The error would suggest that `TBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher` does not directly derive from `IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher`. Does it have an `IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher*` conversion operator instead?  If so, then you would have to dereference the pointer when casting it: `_di_IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher intf = static_cast<IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher*>(* new TBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher);`

Comment: I wrote the declaration in my post : `TBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher= class(TWinRTGenericImportFI<IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherFactory, IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher>)`

Comment: I meant the full declaration, or at least member operators in particular. Also, the declaration/operators of `TWinRTGenericImportFI`, too

Comment: // xxx.BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher
  // DualAPI
  // Implements: xxx.IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher
  // Factory: "xxx.Advertisement.IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherFactory"
  // Instantiable: "IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher"
  `TBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher = class(TWinRTGenericImportFI<IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherFactory, IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher>)
  public
    // -> IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherFactory
    class function Create(advertisementFilter: IBluetoothLEAdvertisementFilter): IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher; overload; static; inline;
  end;`

Comment: `{ TBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher }
// Factories for : "BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher"
// Factory: "Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement.IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherFactory"
// -> IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherFactory

class function TBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher.Create(advertisementFilter: IBluetoothLEAdvertisementFilter): IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher;
begin
  Result := Factory.Create(advertisementFilter);
end;`

Comment: `TWinRTGenericImportFI<F: IInspectable; I: IInspectable> = class(TWinRTGenericImportF<F>)
  public
    class function Create: I; static;
  end;
`

Comment: `{ TWinRTGenericImportFI<F,I> }

class function TWinRTGenericImportFI<F, I>.Create: I;
begin
  Result := I(CreateInstance(TypeInfo(I), FRTClassName));
end;`

Comment: I wanted the **C++** declarations, not the Delphi declarations. But whatever. In this case, the `Create()` method is an actual class method and not a constructor (which is the usual case), so try this instead: `_di_IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher intf = TBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher::Create();`

Comment: Yes but the ::Creat() method is a static method which take an argument : `public:
 static _di_IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher __fastcall Create(_di_IBluetoothLEAdvertisementFilter advertisementFilter)/* overload */;`

Comment: .I think that I have a long trip in delphi internals before being able to use C++Builder. Why delphi does not complain about `Result := TBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher.Create;`.
Thank you, Remy, for your support. I prefer spending some time learning c++/winrt using visual studio because I feel myself more comfortable with C++. I need some update the asynchronous operations (async, await, co_wait, CancellationTokenSource, … ). I hope being able to make a DLL in c++/winrt with a standard C interface and call it from C++builder.

Comment: the Delphi code is calling the parameterless `Create()` method that is inherited from `TWinRTGenericImportFI`

Comment: Not exactly, the IDE shows that in `unit2.pas` the line `Result := TBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher.Create;` (CTRL + Click) is calling `class function TBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher.Create(advertisementFilter: IBluetoothLEAdvertisementFilter): IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher;
begin
  Result := Factory.Create(advertisementFilter);
end;` But I cann not guess where `advertisementFilter` were initialized.

Comment: CTRL + Click on `advertisementFilter` points me to `TBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher = class(TWinRTGenericImportFI<IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherFactory, IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher>)
  public
    // -> IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherFactory
    class function Create(advertisementFilter: IBluetoothLEAdvertisementFilter): IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher; overload; static; inline;
  end;`. But is this an object creation in delphi ?

Comment: the CTRL+Click is taking you to the wrong declaration. Put a breakpoint inside your Delphi function in Unit2 and step into the code with the debugger, that will show you exactly which `Create()` is actually being called at runtime.

Comment: The pascal sources are here: `realwork/common/components/rtl/external/Embarcadero/DelphiBerlin/rtl/win/winrt/Winapi.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement.pas`  and here `realwork/common/components/rtl/external/Embarcadero/DelphiBerlin/rtl/net/System.Win.BluetoothWinRT.pas`.  Line number 599 in the last file shows the creation of `TBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher` instance.

Comment: I was talking about YOUR Delphi code (`CreateADelphiInstance()` calling `TBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher.Create`). Put a breakpoint on that `Create()` call and see where it goes. And as I told you earlier, I don't have a Bluetooth-enabled version of the IDE installed, so I CANT look at Embarcadero's source code myself, that is why I keep asking you to post declarations and such.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: When I debug the code, the delphi IDE debuger is unable to go inside the `TBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher.Create` of my function `CreateADelphiInstance()`  even if I add the concerned rtl pascal source file to my projet and disable dynamic runtime linking. The only way that I found to debug the rtl source code is to add OutputDebugString inside it. But this is not very practical debug process.

Comment: did you enable "Use debug DCUs" in the project options? That allows for stepping through RTL source code without adding RTL units to your project